# Refactoring method

Tags: c#, refactoring

I've following method in the code.I could have some more if conditions in the future.
So just wondering how to re-factor this code from a maintenance point of view.

```
string MyMethod(string filter)
    {
      StringBuilder sbFilter = new StringBuilder(filter);

      if (filter.Contains("A"))
      {
        sbFilter.Append("X");
      }
      if (filter.Contains("B"))
      {
        sbFilter.Append("Y");
      }
      if (filter.Contains("C"))
      {
        sbFilter.Append("Z");
      }
      return sbFilter.ToString();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your from/to combinations into an array, which can easily be modified.
With linq you can select the values:

```
    String FilterMethod(String filter) {
        var fromTo = new[] {"A,X","B,Y","C,Z"};
        return String.Concat(
            from pair in fromTo
            let split= pair.Split(',')
            where split.Length == 2 && filter.Contains(split[0])
            select split[1]
        );
    }
```

You can even make a one-liner:

```
    String FilterMethod2(String filter) {
        return String.Concat(
            from pair in new[] { "A,X", "B,Y", "C,Z" }
            let split = pair.Split(',')
            where split.Length == 2 && filter.Contains(split[0])
            select split[1]
        );
    }
```

Comment: Making something a one-liner is usually the opposite of helpful when future maintenance and enhancements are even a passing concern.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a list of tuples:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string>[] mappings = new [] 
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("A", "X"), 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("B", "Y"), 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("C", "Z"), 
};

string MyMethod(string filter)
{
    var sbFilter = new StringBuilder(filter);

    foreach (var m in mappings)
    {
        if (filter.Contains(m.Key))
            sbFilter.Append(m.Value);
    }

    return sbFilter.ToString();
}
```

Which can be written even more concisely using LINQ:

```
string MyMethod(string filter)
{
    return filter + string.Concat(mappings
        .Where(m => filter.Contains(m.Key))
        .Select(m => m.Value));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As @ Jakub Dąbek wrote in his comment, this question is more suitable for code review forum, but I think that using a `SortedDictionary` will make your code more maintainable and clear.
 **that way you will never have the need to change** `MyMethod` **function**.
 based on your example,
 i would do something like that (please see my comments inside the code):

```
private SortedDictionary<string, string> _Dic;
public SortedDictionary<string, string> Dic
{
    get
    {
        if (_Dic == null)
        {
            _Dic = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

            _Dic.Add("A", "X");
            _Dic.Add("B", "Y");
            _Dic.Add("C", "Z");
            // add more key-pair values in the future
            return _Dic;
        }
        else
        {
            return _Dic;
        }
    }

    set
    {
        // important: here you can get your valus from external source!
        _Dic = value;
    }
}

string MyMethod(string filter)
{
    StringBuilder sbFilter = new StringBuilder(filter);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> itm in Dic)
    {
        if (filter.Contains(itm.Key))
        {
            sbFilter.Append(Dic[itm.Key]);
        }
    }

    return sbFilter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is generally the correct idea, but it's not functionally equivalent to OP's code since iterating a .NET `Dictionary<>` does not guarantee any particular order.

Comment: thanks for your comment, did not knew that, what about `HashSet` or `SortedDictionary`?

Comment: Same thing with `HashSet`, those data structures are both [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), meaning that they provide `O(1)` average key lookup time. But in order to do this, keys need to be hashed, and the hash number is the one which will affect the order in memory.

Comment: @Groo, good point,if i understood properly i changed to `SortedDictionary`. MSDN: Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted on the key.

Comment: Gaaaaah I am not a fan of all that logic being jammed into the getter!

Comment: @P.Roe I did not understand "logic being jammed into the getter" what do you mean?

Comment: @jonathana Placing logic in a getter or setter should be a last resort and even then it should be placed in a real method call that can be independently tested and then included in the get/set call imo.

Comment: @P.Roe in real life a logic like adding keys and values to a dictionary i do in a real method, for the simplicity of the code in the answer here in stack overflow its written in the `get` property method.